# How do I call a local shell script from a web server?

Tags: apache, shell, ubuntu, nginx, webserver

I am running Ubuntu 11 and I would like to setup a simple webserver that responds to an http request by calling a local script with the GET or POST parameters. This script (already written) does some stuff and creates a file.  This file should be made available at a URL, and the webserver should then make an http request to another server telling it to download the created file.

How would I go about setting this up?  I'm not a total beginner with linux, but I wouldn't say I know it well either.

What webserver should I use?  How do I give permission for the script to access local resources to create the file in question?  I'm not too concerned with security or anything, this is for a personal experiment (I have control over all the computers involved).  I've used apache before, but I've never set it up.

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[This tutorial looks good](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/run-shell-script-from-web-page/), but it's a bit brief.

I have apache installed.  If you don't: `sudo apt-get install apache2`.

```
cd /usr/lib/cgi-bin

# Make a file and let everyone execute it
sudo touch test.sh && chmod a+x test.sh
```

Then put the some code in the file.  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# get today's date
OUTPUT="$(date)"
# You must add following two lines before
# outputting data to the web browser from shell
# script
 echo "Content-type: text/html"
 echo ""
 echo "<html><head><title>Demo</title></head><body>"
 echo "Today is $OUTPUT <br>"
 echo "Current directory is $(pwd) <br>"
 echo "Shell Script name is $0"
 echo "</body></html>"
```

And finally open your browser and type http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.sh

If all goes well (as it did for me) you should see...

> Today is Sun Dec 4 ...
>   Current directory is /usr/lib/cgi-bin Shell
>   Shell Script name is /usr/lib/cgi-bin/test.sh

Comment: We also have to enable `mod_cg`i `a2enmod cgi` if not already enabled

Comment: on my system, I used the following commands to activate mod_cgi:

    `sudo a2enmod cgi`  
    `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: @TonoNam I recommend asking another question and linking to this one. I don't know the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but how could I separate it from the different vhosts?

Comment: @Daniel I'd recommend asking that as a separate question

Comment: How about permissions. I'm unable to create a directory. It gives permissions denied. Using sudo doesn't help as well

Comment: Is this really the canonical way that apache can run random shell scripts?

Comment: I get `Not Found
The requested URL /cgi-bin/test.sh was not found on this server.`

Comment: @AlexanderMills it could be that you're not talking to apache, or a configuration difference. This was 7+ years ago, so I'm not sure if cgi-bin is even enabled by default anymore