# Errno 13 Permission denied bash script and apache2

Tags: python, linux, bash, apache

I'm trying to run a bash script to get values from BMP280 sensor.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
read_bme280 --i2c-address 0x76
```

The web page is blank, in error.log I get:

```
[Tue Mar 29 07:20:40.579423 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 1280] [client 10.20.30.127:34334] AH01215: Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Mar 29 07:20:40.580102 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 1280] [client 10.20.30.127:34334] AH01215:   File "/usr/local/bin/read_bme280", line 9, in <module>
[Tue Mar 29 07:20:40.580589 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 1280] [client 10.20.30.127:34334] AH01215:     
[Tue Mar 29 07:20:40.581016 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 1280] [client 10.20.30.127:34334] AH01215: load_entry_point('bme280==0.2', 'console_scripts', 'read_bme280')()
[Tue Mar 29 07:20:40.581669 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 1280] [client 10.20.30.127:34334] AH01215:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bme280/bme280.py", line 210, in main
[Tue Mar 29 07:20:40.582426 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 1280] [client 10.20.30.127:34334] AH01215:     
[Tue Mar 29 07:20:40.582811 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 1280] [client 10.20.30.127:34334] AH01215: bme280_i2c.set_default_bus(int(args.i2c_bus))
[Tue Mar 29 07:20:40.583487 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 1280] [client 10.20.30.127:34334] AH01215:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bme280/bme280_i2c.py", line 22, in set_default_bus
[Tue Mar 29 07:20:40.583991 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 1280] [client 10.20.30.127:34334] AH01215:     
[Tue Mar 29 07:20:40.584345 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 1280] [client 10.20.30.127:34334] AH01215: default_bus = smbus.SMBus(bus_number)
[Tue Mar 29 07:20:40.584836 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 1280] [client 10.20.30.127:34334] AH01215: IOError
[Tue Mar 29 07:20:40.587657 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 1280] [client 10.20.30.127:34334] AH01215: : [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

From the cli, the script runs just fine.
Can't figure out where is the "Permission denied" problem.

Comment: You cannot directly run bash script from apache server. Have a look in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8378332/1075324. tl;dr, configure cgi-bin in apache and run script from there.

Comment: As per the traceback, the `www-data` user lacks the privilege to call `smbus.SMBus()`?

Comment: user www-data is added to group i2c: 

# groups www-data
www-data : www-data i2c

Comment: Your websever needs to know how to execute and serve the shell script.

Answer (score 0):

If tte file is owned by root, then try to `chmod +s /usr/local/bin/read_bme280`. It should allow the script to run with root privileges thus have access to everything.

As a security precaution you could make sure that other users can't edit this file.

Comment: No, don't run scripts via web as root permission.

Comment: What would be the problem to do that if the script is read-only?
It's likely to be more dangerous to add the www-data user to the group that has access to the i2c bus.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with php:

```
  <?php
$url1=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Refresh: 10; URL=$url1");

$output = shell_exec('read_bme280 --i2c-address 0x76');

$parts = explode("\n", $output);

echo "<pre>";

echo "<h2>Temp: " . $parts[2] . "</h2><br />";
echo "<h2>Humidity: " . $parts[1] . "</h2><br />";
echo "<h2>Pressure: " . $parts[0] . "</h2>";
```